# Run Xamarin android unit tests for result

Tags: automation, xamarin.android, continuous-integration, nunit

I had a question regarding the [Test APK](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/3f587f51b4bd36eab229069d7dce293659d8da62/Documentation/building/unix-instructions.md#running-individual-apk-projects) topic.

Is there a way to use the [`tests/RunApkTests.targets`](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/3f587f51b4bd36eab229069d7dce293659d8da62/tests/RunApkTests.targets) and
[`build-tools/scripts/TestApks.targets`](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/3f587f51b4bd36eab229069d7dce293659d8da62/build-tools/scripts/TestApks.targets)
files. so I can reuse the targets to run my own android unit tests and get results as part as our continuous integration?

I tried using the [NUnit Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/automate-android-nunit-test) with no success. I also created an issue [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs/issues/65) but I kept researching and found some potentially useful targets there.

I'd rather use these targets through a nuget package as opposed to manually downloading the target files and their associated files.

Any suggestions?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: These tests are more geared for the Xamarin.Android framework. Is there any reason why you would need to run the framework's unit tests against your project? Rather you should aim to run your own unit tests against your APK.

Comment: End goal is to be able to unit test android specific functionality for a xamarin project on a device and receive test results. If there is a better way to do that. I'm all eyes and ears!